# Adding distance to geographic point

Tags: coordinate-system

Given an odometry, a direction and a point where I'm, I would like to change my current position according to these variables.

Let's say `dLat` and `dLon` are the difference of latitude and longitude between where I'm and where I would like to go. Let's assume the radius of the Earth equals 6,371,000.0 meters.

With papers and a pen, I found some equations to solve my problem : (ok, my background in maths could be better)

First of all, I calculate the degrees of each angle :

```
degreesAngleLat = 90 * dlat / (abs(dlon) + abs(dlat))
degreesAngleLon = 90 * dlon / (abs(dlon) + abs(dlat))
```

Then, I'll use some trigonometry to find the distance of the latitude and longitude :

```
odoLat = cos(degreesAngleLon * pi / 180) * odometry // I know, lattitude and longitude are reversed
odoLon = cos(degreesAngleLat * pi / 180) * odometry
```

Once I compute the direction, I want to know how many meters I have made in latitude and in longitude. I draw a rectangle, 1 side is my current position, the opposite is where I should be (with the odometry and the angle). So, I split it in 2 right-angle triangles. I know the hypotenuse, the angle, I can calculate the adjacent side. If I'm not wrong, cos(angle) = adjacent/hypotenuse.

After that, I convert this odometry to an angle :

```
deltaAngleLon = asin(odoLon/2/earthRadiusM) / pi * 180 * 2
deltaAngleLat = asin(odoLat/2/earthRadiusM) / pi * 180 * 2
```

Why `* 2` ? Between 2 points on the earth's surface and the centre of the earth, an isosceles rectangle can be drawn. I use only half of the odometry to get a rectangular triangle (hence the / 2), then I multiply the angle obtained by 2 to match the correct odometry.

I have the odometry (or distance) for the latitude and longitude, And I would like to convert them into an angle. I draw my isoscele rectangle between the center of the earth and the 2 points in the surface. I draw 2 right-angle triangles in this triangle. I assume the segment is the size of the radius of the earth (in mathematics, I know it's wrong, but in this case, I think it can only add more accuracy ?) then, I have the size of the hypotenuse, the size of the side of the opposite angle (odometry / 2), I can calculate the angle : sin(angle/2) = odometry/2/radius.

Finally, I "just" have to add these delta to my current position (and modify the signs if needed).
Using maths, it's working... I thought...
Yes, it's working in the position `0.0, 0.0`, but not in Europe...

Let's say :

```
odometry = 100
dLat = 1
dLon = 1
```

With these steps, I can find :

```
deltaAngleLat = 0.000636
deltaAngleLon = 0.000636
```

I used a [website](https://www.sunearthtools.com/fr/tools/distance.php) to calculate the distance, between the null point and this coordinate, it gives me 100m, perfect. (and an angle of 45°, nice)
But, when I add them to my current position, in France in example, I find 83.9m and an angle of 42.5...

My current position : 50.426753, 2.828529

With deltaAngle added : 50.427389, 2.829165

What am I doing wrong ? I know the radius isn't the same everywhere, but given this huge error, I don't think it's linked ?

This is my little program in Go : https://play.golang.org/p/znC98p7xAM9

Comment: You can't wing the math when it comes to geodesy. It's far better to use published code than write your own, and to use existing helper functions where possible (e.g., for degree-radian conversion, which appears to be an issue here)

Comment: Could you tell me please where is the problem for the degree-radian conversion ?

Comment: Your sines and cosines are suspect and your conversion has a spurious `* 2`

Comment: Between 2 points on the earth's surface and the centre of the earth, an isosceles rectangle can be drawn. I use only half of the odometry to get a rectangular triangle (hence the / 2), then I multiply the angle obtained by 2 to match the correct odometry. It's hard, without a schema, to explained why I used the sines and cosines... I'll try in the next comment

Comment: For the cosines : Once I compute the direction, I want to know how many meters I have made in latitude and in longitude. I draw a rectangle, 1 side is my current position, the opposite is where I should be (with the odometry and the angle). So, I split it in 2 right-angle triangles. I know the hypotenuse, the angle, I can calculate the adjacent side. If I'm not wrong, cos(angle) = adjacent/hypotenuse. So yes, I should move the odometry in the sines next to the cosines. (the odometry is the hypotenuse)

Comment: For the sines : I moslty explained it in my 2nd comment, I have the odometry (or distance) for the latitude and longitude, And I would like to convert them into an angle. I draw my isoscele rectangle between the center of the earth and the 2 points in the surface. I draw 2 right-angle triangles in this triangle. I assume the segment is the size of the radius of the earth (in mathematics, I know it's wrong, but in this case, I think it can only add more accuracy ?) then, I have the size of the hypotenuse, the size of the side of the opposite angle (odometry / 2), I can calculate the angle :

Comment: sin(angle/2) = odometry/2/radius. So yes here I made a mistake, it should be asin. I corrected it in my code, and I still get the same result

Comment: And yes, I should search publised code,  but I would love to understand why it works near the null point, but not in France (or I suppose far from it)

Comment: Comments are illegible for this purpose; edit your question to provide clarifications. Be sure to ask only one question.

Comment: I already did it

Comment: You state that you are given an distance, initial direction and starting point. How did you calculate your dLat, dLon? Also, keep in mind that the length of degrees of longitude depends on your latitude. They get smaller as you approach the poles.

Comment: If you truly want to treat the Earth as a sphere and get good results, I would suggest using [spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry). [Movable Type](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) also has scripts for such calculation with available code if you want to look into the specific formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming several things that are not correct, but the biggest is in the calculation of what parallel segments should be. Think of the triangle you are drawing between two points that are located on the same parallel and the center of the sphere, move those points to the north. Their longitudes remain the same, but the drawn triangle is increasingly sharp, the angle formed becomes smaller, because that angle is not the difference in longitudes between the two points, except at the equator.

Then, you are comparing straight distances between points on a spherical surface, against curved distances against points on a spherical or ellipsoidal surface, which beyond the variation that may be in the radius, are simply different distances. Since the radius of the earth is so large compared to the distances you are calculating, you will see the absolute errors as small. I even think that you are calculating odoLat and odoLong in an inverted way (but as long as you use the same variation in latitude than in longitude you will not notice). And the way to calculate the direction is a bit wrong too: the internal angles of a spherical triangle don't add up to 180º. But all these things will produce minor errors under your circumstances, in comparison with the above.

The first approximation to the calculations that you want to do should be based on spherical trigonometry.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I think your first paragraph is my main problem. I'm aware of the curved distance, but it shouldn't lead to an error of 16%. Thank you

Comment: That triangle should be drawn on a plane parallel to the plane of the equator, so that the angle included represents the difference in longitude between the points. The radius of the parallel is the radius of the sphere multiplied by the cosine of latitude. That would improve the approach. However, it is much better decision to understand spherical trigonometry and base the calculations on it, than to keep an approximation just for not using the proper mathematical tool.

Comment: You're right, and I would learn from it. Thank you again.